# StackFrame, нет имени файла и номера строки

Tags: c#, .net

Использую debug - сборку приложения, и хотел бы получить имя строки вызова и имя файла. Однако, в случае имени файла, в текущем кадре хранится значение null, а номера строки(столбца также) всегда равны 0. Почему это происходит? Выдержки кода:

```
StackFrame sf = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1); // да, мне нужен *предыдущий* кадр
string file = sf.GetFileName(); // здесь null(всегда)
string func = sf.GetMethod().Name; // здесь есть имя метода 
int line = sf.GetFileLineNumber(); // здесь 0(всегда)
// и так далее
```

Также, хотелось бы отметить, что StackFrame для конструктора класса всегда возвращает в виде имени метода следующее значение: *.ctor* Понятно, что сокращение слова Constructor(возможно), но хотелось бы полное имя получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покопавшись ещё более глубоко, проблема была решена следующим образом:

```
StackFrame sf = new StackFrame(1, true);  // второй аргумент конструктора включает запись об источнике(файл, строки)
string file = sf.GetFileName();
string func = "";
if (sf.GetMethod().Name.StartsWith(".")) // проверяем на наличие символа '.' в имени "метода" 
    func = sf.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name + ".Constructor"; // устанавливаем имя конструктора через класс: Класс.Конструктор
else
    func = sf.GetMethod().Name;
func += "(";
foreach (var t in sf.GetMethod().GetParameters()) // получаем и перечисляем все параметры методов и добавляем к строке
    func += t.ToString() + ", ";
if (sf.GetMethod().GetParameters().Length > 0)
    func = func.Remove(func.Length - 2);
func += ")";
// выполняется остальной нужный код...
```

В результате:

- Информация о файле выводится корректно
- Информация о номере строки выводится корректно
- Вывод конструктора выглядит читаемым(Класс.Конструктор)
- Также, выводятся параметры с типами и именами

Может быть, кому-то я помогу.